# What are the pros and cons when choosing ajax enabled WCF service in an asp.net webform application?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, wcf

I have just experimented my first `ajax enabled WCF service` in a sample `asp.net webform` application... If i have 10-15 pages in my webapplication which involves `add,edit,view and delete` operations, is it possible to make them `ajax post and get` without using `.cs(codebehind)` of all pages...

What are the pros and cons when choosing ajax enabled WCF service in an asp.net webform application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, if you want to implement the server side of jQuery Ajax calls, you can do this with either ASMX or WCF services. You can find a short comparison between these two [here](http://www.keithelder.net/blog/archive/2008/10/17/WCF-vs-ASMX-WebServices.aspx). WCF is more modern technology and will be my preferred choice for new projects. It can provide you with the following:

- Help you program against an interface
- It will serialize/deserialize objects to JSON for you. No need for JSON libraries
- Provides client methods that you can use (via the ScriptManager). It is also easy to use jQuery if you prefer

As an disadvantage I would say that it will take you some time to learn the technology. I found that proper configuration of web.config was a little tricky.

I usually have a single svc service that serves all Ajax requests. You can implement as many methods as you want in a single service. The services are called from different pages.

Comment: @Kgiannakakis well said.. I implemented a page with complete HTML Controls including add edit delete functionalities... It is quite interesting.... But i want to know about cons when hosting this application to a server...